# How to open last activity from notification status bar?

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I want to open last started activity by tapping on the notification in status bar. Suppose I start an Activity A (main activity of my app), this activity sends a notification to notification status bar. activity A also opens an activity B and B opens another activity C. From C i press home button. Now i want to go again to my app so from notification bar i tap on notification (which was sent by A). Here the notification should start activity C because it was last opened.

I did search on this but didn't find proper answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Why not design it in such a way that an extra is passed in the Intent and then the activity handles it accordingly.

Comment: Question is related to this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079652/custom-notification

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5502950/1445568

Comment: because the work must be done before openning the activity

Comment: _+1_ here is the best solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448840/android-how-to-open-last-activity-when-tapping-notification

Answer (score 24):

Few days back I got very very simple solution for my problem. Instead of iterating through `recentTasks` and getting our task and then getting `baseIntent` through it, we can do simple thing as follows:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
```

`baseIntent` contains the same parameters as above `Intent` has. Hence instead of grabbing `baseIntent` from `recentTasks`, it's quite good to use above code.

This `notificationIntent` will then be passed to `pendingIntent` for further use.

Provided: `MainActivity` is the very first activity when we launch our app and in AndroidManifest.xml it must contain `IntentFilters` of `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` and `ACTION_MAIN`.

Comment: Works like a charm, i used a login activity that opens another activity based on some parameters. Now when a user opens the app by tapping the notification, it now reopens the app without stacking the activities!

Comment: I want to add, use android:launchMode="singleTop" in manifest and use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK in intent.

Answer (score 7):

Since i didnt get any answer after searching on this, i stopped trying but just some days before i started trying again and i found out the SOLUTION. :) I am putting it here.

But first of all i just wanted to redefine my problem and it was :: "Getting background task to foreground from status notification bar" i.e., When i put my app to background by pressing home button and then i make it appear to foreground, all activities should come to foreground in the same order as they are in stack of the app.

For this, i needed a Pending Intent that whenever fired brings my app to foreground.

Here, as my app starts, a notification is put on the status bar that remains there till my app runs on device.

So here is the code i tried::

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification();
notification.flag = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

Intent nIntent = new Intent();

final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

final List<RecentTaskInfo> recentTaskInfos = am.getRecentTasks(1024,0);
String myPkgNm = getPackageName();

if (!recentTaskInfos.isEmpty()) {
     RecentTaskInfo recentTaskInfo;
     final int size = recentTaskInfo.size();
     for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
         recentTaskInfo = recentTaskInfos.get(i);
         if (recentTaskInfo.baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName().equals(myPkgNm)) {
             nIntent = recentTaskInfo.baseIntent;
             nIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         }
     }
 }
 PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, nIntent, 0);
 notification.setLatestEventInfo(getContext(), "some Title", "some text", pi);
 nm.notify(0,notification);
```

The main key here is the baseIntent, whose documentation says:
    *The original Intent used to launch the task. You can use this Intent to re-launch 
    the task (if it is no longer running) or bring the current task to the front.*

Documentation of FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK says: *When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started; instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the screen with the state it was last in.*

I used it first but it doesnt work as it says and there are many questions on this..

Anyways.. till now, i found this way good for bringing task to front just as icon on the home screen of android does.

But please tell me cons of this way so that i can improve.

:)

Comment: Content.ACTIVITY_SERVICE should be Context... Can't edit because I need a minimum of 6 character changes :|

Comment: @Foobar: Make the change as you suggested. ;)

Comment: Awsome. But I wanna say add you have to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried this:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class)
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

The above codes instruct Android to open the last activity, whether it's the main activity or a preference activity [that's currently in the foreground] that you used to create/launch the icon in the notification bar in the first place.

`ACTION_MAIN` and `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` refer to `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>` and `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>` directives respectively in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 2):

Always worked for me.

## Manifest

```
launchMode="singleTop" #For Launcher activity
never use "singleTask" as a launchMode
set no launchMode for other activities. (if not needed)
```

## Notification Intent

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
notificationIntent.setClass(this, LaucherActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```