# Display notification every time I minimize app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

**Context:**

My app has 5 activities:

- SplashScreenActivity - starts service
- MainActivity - selects Activity 1,2 or 3
- Activity 1
- Activity 2
- Activity 3

Currently I create notification in *onCreate* method of the service, which display recent activity after touching, based on

1. [android How to open last activity when tapping notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448840/android-how-to-open-last-activity-when-tapping-notification)
2. [Resume application and stack from notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502427/resume-application-and-stack-from-notification)
3. [How to open last activity from notification status bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188412/how-to-open-last-activity-from-notification-status-bar)

**Problem**

[setOngoing](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setOngoing(boolean)) method *Notification.Builder* is annoying - is always here, independent if my app is in foreground or not. So I change to the [setAutoCancel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setAutoCancel(boolean)) method, but works only for first use.
Example:

I run my app - splashscreen activity (notification is shown) -> main activity -> select Activity 1 - minimize. Now click notification - brings Activity 1 (OK), but notification is dismissed and never shown.

**Question**

> How to display notification, every time I minimize app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple override **onPause** and put the notification logic there.

Comment: Sure, this was my first thought, but on every activity?

Comment: Create a service and start that service in every activity that you want to display a notification on.

Comment: I already created service, read description please

Comment: I'm not seeing the code but run the service then.

Comment: Thanks, but I am completely lost from your comments. Service is already started in splashscreen activity, i dont need start service again, because is already started

Comment: In that case, when your app leaves the foreground inform the service to show the notification.

Comment: But how inform service?